# While displaying data from API response I am getting this error: **ERROR TypeError: Cannot create property 'validator' on string**

Tags: angular, angular6, angular-reactive-forms, formarray

For displaying API response to the template file, I used reactive forms. My project requirement is that if API response contains some data then display it and I can add dynamic data too and all those data should be store in DB. If API response is empty then too I can add dynamic data and that will also going to store in DB.

Used form array and following is my code:

*ts file:*

```
orderForm: FormGroup;
items: FormArray;

ngOnInit() {

    if(this.data.data && this.data.data.length) {
      this.orderForm = this.formBuilder.group({
        items: this.formBuilder.array([ ])
      })

      this.setCheckBoxValue()
    }
    else {
      this.createBlankItem();
    }
  }

setCheckBoxValue() {
    this.items = this.orderForm.get('items') as FormArray;
    this.data.data.forEach((element) => {
      this.items.push(this.formBuilder.group({
        checked: element,
        selected: true
      }))
    });
  }

createBlankItem(): FormGroup {
    return this.formBuilder.group({
      checked: '',
      selected: false
    })
  }

removeDynamicCheckBox(i) {
    this.items.removeAt(i);
  }

  addDynamicCheckBox() {
    this.items = this.orderForm.get('items') as FormArray;
    this.items.push(this.createItem());
  }
```

*template file:*

```
<div [formGroup]="orderForm">
      <div formArrayName="items" *ngFor="let item of orderForm.get('items').controls; let i=index">
        <div class="row" [formGroupName]="i">
          <div class="col-lg-1 col-md-1 col-sm-1 col-xs-1">
            <mat-checkbox [formControl]="item.controls.checked.value" class="ml-a" [checked]="item.controls.selected.value">
            </mat-checkbox>
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-10 col-md-10 col-sm-10 col-xs-10">
            <mat-form-field 
            floatPlaceholder="never" class="margin-top-25px example-full-width" >
                <input 
                matInput
                class="input"
                value="{{item.controls.checked.value}}"
                >
            </mat-form-field>
          </div>
          <!-- <div class="col-lg-1 col-md-1 col-sm-1 col-xs-1">
              <a href="" (click)="removeDynamicCheckBox(i)">X</a>      
          </div> -->
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <button mat-raised-button (click)="addDynamicCheckBox()">Add</button>
    </div>
```

I am getting what I want but in console, I am getting this error:

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot create property 'validator' on string

Please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

In the checkbox HTML input, rewrite the formControl directive.

```
<mat-checkbox [formControl]="item" class="ml-a" [checked]="item.controls.selected.value">
            </mat-checkbox>
```

also, in the ts file, modify the setCheckBoxValue method to add FormControl rather than FormArray

```
setCheckBoxValue() {
        this.items = this.orderForm.get('items') as FormArray;
        this.data.data.forEach((element) => {
            let control = new FormControl(true);
            this.items.push(control)
        });
    }
```

Comment: By doing this, I am getting this error: *ERROR TypeError: control.registerOnChange is not a function*

Comment: Thank you @cobra. But this is not giving me what I want

Comment: Yes.. I wrote in my question that I want to display data from API response, and from that API response I have to display checkbox selected with text coming from API response. I have put the button *Add* which will add dynamic fields.